# Extract table from word

Tags: java, ms-word, aspose

I want extract all table in Word this code extract only the first table

whatever number of table in word doc `tables.size()  return 1`

`tables = Arrays.asList(tempDoc.getChildNodes(NodeType.TABLE, true)`

Code:

```
import com.aspose.words.Document;
import com.aspose.words.NodeType;
import com.aspose.words.Paragraph;
import com.aspose.words.Table;

public class ExtractTableFromWord {
static List<Node> tables;

// static List<Node> tables = new ArrayList<Node>();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new Document("D://New folder//21.docx");

    // Create a clone of the document
    Document tempDoc = doc.deepClone();
    for (int j = 0; j < doc.getPageCount(); j++) {

        tables = Arrays.asList(tempDoc.getChildNodes(NodeType.TABLE, true)
                .toArray());
        System.out.println(tables.size() + "-------------");
    }
    // Clear tempDoc
    tempDoc.getSections().clear();
    tempDoc.ensureMinimum();

    for (int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++) {
        Table docTable = (Table) tables.get(i);
        Table docTableCopy = (Table) docTable.deepClone(true);

        // Insert table into document
        tempDoc.getFirstSection().getBody().insertAfter(docTableCopy,
                tempDoc.getFirstSection().getBody().getFirstParagraph());

        // Insert paragraph between tables
        tempDoc.getFirstSection().getBody().insertAfter(
                new Paragraph(tempDoc),
                tempDoc.getFirstSection().getBody().getFirstParagraph());
    }

    tempDoc.save("D:\\out put\\outTables.html");

}
}
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: aspose library
import
import com.aspose.words.Document;
import com.aspose.words.NodeType;
import com.aspose.words.Paragraph;
import com.aspose.words.Table;
@LutzHorn

Comment: I ran your code with one of the documents at my end, it extracted all the tables. Please try the latest version of Aspose.Words. If still, it does not work, post the sample Word document.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4cxDnPAjctLRi1NckFYT0g4M1E
this word doc and all word doc extract only the first table